# Forcefully update the component on updated value inside the render method react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to forcefully rerender the complete component on value change inside the render function.
Below is a sample code to explain my problem. Profile component I am calling after the login and it's called and two functions inside this getting called and the value is set in the state. Now I am on another screen where I am updating `mssidnNumber` inside the context and that change I can see in the Profile render() function `val`. `let val = this.context.mssidnNumber;` and this `val` value will change on condition so on this basis I am trying to rerender the complete Profile component again so all values will update. How can I do this please help? Is that possible?

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View} from 'react-native';
    
    class Profile extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
      this.Profilefunction();
      }
      
      Profilefunction = () =>{
      
      this.setState({})
      await this.profile2fucntion();
      }
      
      profile2fucntion =() => {
      }
    
      render() {
      let val = this.context.mssidnNumber;
        return (
          <View>
    
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Profile;
```

Comment: What and where are you enqueueing any state updates? This looks like incomplete code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes this is not code , dummy I have wrote , my code is quite long , I wrote this to explain the question

Comment: This isn't enough code to be (a) complete, and (b) reproducible. You got the minimal part, but you need all three. We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: my question is , is there any way to forecfully rerdner the complete componenet ,like in redner I am using let val = this.context.mssidnNumber; , so here val will change may time  and on change of val i want to rerender componenet

Comment: If you are at a point where you need to "force" React to rerender then you are probably doing something wrong. It's a code smell. But if you really need to, then yes, there is [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).

Comment: so how can I call inside the render , like if val value will chnage will call forceupdate()

Comment: Uh, you don't want to force render from the method that is rendering the component, that will create a render loop. `render` is a pure function, there should be ***zero*** side-effects. Like I said, needing to force a render usually means you're not updating state correctly. State updates should trigger a rerender. Changes to the context state, i.e. `this.context.mssidnNumber` should again, trigger a rerender.